# Which view function will trigger

Tags: swift, view

This question is related to view life cycle .Which view function will be triggered after the action of button is executed.

My requirement is to hide some buttons or subView conditionally after some action is performed.

Comment: Your question is way too broad to be considered on topic here. Moreover, you didn't even specify which platform your question is about (iOS or macOS).

Answer (score 0):

There is no life cycle on that , you have to connect the button as `IBAction` / add target , and hide anyThing inside it